# Will java allow to use functional interfaces as methods?

Tags: java, lambda, closures, java-8

With the new java lambdas and the concept of functional interfaces, will it be possible to treat those functional interfaces as methods?

```
interface Func { void execute(int i); }

void call(Func f)
{
    f(1); //instead of f.execute(1);
}
```

I found a lot of information about the syntax of actual lambda expressions, but nothing about this.

Comment: I doubt it. But you'll be able to save on typing when you implement that interface: something like `call( (i) -> System.out.println(i); )`

Comment: @NimChimpsky Actually it is located in http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/, because the JDK8 still does not contain all lambda project functionality as far as I understand.

Answer (score 15):

#### Your proposition

What you propose has been discussed on the lambda-dev mailing list before:

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-February/004518.html

It was mainly rejected because of the various problems related to ambiguity that would arise for the parser / compiler. Or in Brian Goetz's terms:

> I think, ultimately, this is just discomfort with the committment to functional interfaces instead of function types, and an attempt to backpedal towards a wishy-washy middle ground.  I don't see this as offering a compelling enough benefit.

If you feel that such *"wishy-washy"* features would still add value to the Java language, you can try your luck again on one of the lambda mailing lists, maybe with compelling arguments :-)

#### An alternative

It is possible, but probably not as elegantly as in JavaScript as your example syntax suggests. According to the latest [state-of-the-lambda by Brian Goetz](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html), there will be method references as mentioned in chapters

> 8 Method references
>
> [...]
>
> 9 Kinds of method references
>
> [...] There are actually three different kinds of method references, each
>   with slightly different syntax:
>
> - A static method
> - An instance method of a particular object
> - An instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type

So in fact, your example would have to be rephrased along these lines:

```
interface Func { void execute(int i); }

void call(Block<Integer> block)
{
    block.run(1); //instead of f.execute(1);
}
```

You can now pass a reference to that execute method:

```
// Disclaimer: I didn't check this against a JDK8 compiler...
Func f = (i) -> { ; }; // Empty sample implementation
call(f::execute)
```

In other words, the "functional" style is to be implemented at the declaration-site of your call method, not at the use-site. But as with JavaScript, the use-site doesn't have to know about the name of the concrete method in `Func`. It can just accept a `Block` for methods returning `void`, or a `Callable` for methods returning a value.

Note that on JDK's Mercurial repository, things have changed already. You won't find `run()` any more, as mentioned in the state of the lambda. Other interesting types can be found in the java.util.functions package:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/function

Comment: If that example and the Block method pointer does what it seems to do, you don't need the Func interface at all? You can just do `call(this::myMethodThatTakesAnInteger)`?

Comment: @Thilo: According to the [State of the Lambda 4](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html), yes. Their examples use `System::exit` and similar methods, which you could pass to the above `call(Block<Integer> block)` method

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you imply that given the functional interface Mapper declared as follows

```
interface Mapper<T,U> {
   public U map(T t);
}
```

If I implement this functional interface with a lambda expression as follows:

```
Mapper<Integer,String> itoa = (n) -> String.valueOf(n);
```

You would like to invoke the function interface as follows:

```
String val = itoa(10); //would yield "10"
```

And not as it is today:

```
String val = itoa.map(10);
```

I guess, the first invocation is syntactic sugar for the second one.

I have not read in any documentation or the mailing lists that they are planning to provide this feature in the coming release of the JDK. But I guess you could ask the question in the [lambda mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/lambda-dev). I don't see a reason why this could not be implemented.

Comment: For Java 8, such a "heavy" change is likely to be out of scope. I'm guessing that the implications for the parser and compiler are non-negligible, as properties, method arguments, local variables and other identifiers suddenly share semantic scope with methods, which are an entirely different universe to today's Java parser -- it would be very nice, of course!

Comment: ... as a matter of fact, I had vaguely remembered such a discussion on the lambda-dev mailing list: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-February/004518.html. It was rejected quite quickly without long discussion...

Comment: @LukasEder This is a great reference. Thanks for sharing it. I've got to say that with the exception of the namespace issues, all other arguments sounded irrelevant to me, but you’re right, it looks like the EG has already decided on this and they won’t change their mind, at least not for this release.