# How to indirectly run a method reference in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

The general questions are:

- When using the syntax `object::aMethod`, can it be converted to a type such as `MethodHandle` as a functional interface?
- If no, how can a method reference be indirectly invoked in Java 8 if at all possible?

As an example, imagine we'd like to have a `MethodRefRunner` as:

```
class MethodRefRunner {
  static void execute(Object target, WHATTYPE mref, Object... args) {
    mref.apply(args);
  }
}
```

And it can be used as: `MethodRefRunner.execute(o, o::someMethod, someParam)`

In the above snippet, one option for `WHATTYPE` is `java.util.function.Function` but very restrictive. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13173903/248082) mentions, prior to version b75, there was a `java.util.function.Block` was available and might be handy.

On the other side, any chance that `WHATTYPE` could be in some way converted to a `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle`?

*Note* to Java experts: Please refine the title of the questions as needed.

Comment: In Scala, you can coerce a *method* into a *function value*, this is the *eta expansion* (there is a difference between *method* and *function* in Scala). As for the case you describe, the Scala compiler is smart enough to accept both.

Comment: @Beryllium Indeed nice contrast and that's also why I was wondering about the reason Java 8 has not opt for it.

Comment: @nobeh Java 8 is sticking with functional interfaces because adding function types would have involved much bigger changes to the language. They may come later.

Comment: @nobeh this sucks. they should reconsider adding function types in next updates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do what you want.  WHATTYPE is going to have to be a functional interface—not necessarily `Function`, but one whose single abstract method matches `somemethod`. It's an ordinary interface type, subject to the usual rules governing Java types.  `java.util.function.Block` was an ordinary interface type like this, and not special in the way that you seem to think.  (It's still around, by the way, now called `Consumer`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, the question is that is there any way to convert a method reference (or a lambda expression) to a `MethodHandle` at runtime such that it can be invoked?

Comment: Sorry, I think the answer is still no.  The reason (AFAIK) is that any way of doing so would have to have a fixed starting point in the form a particular lambda implementation. But the intention is not to constrain the implementation — the runtime can choose "dynamically spun inner classes, wrapper classes around method handles, dynamic proxies, method handle proxies, or other as yet unknown mechanisms". (http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-November/004224.html).  So if there is in fact some way of doing what you want, it's always going to be VM-dependent.

Comment: I found a discussion thread from November 2012, but it's not clear that this went anywhere: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-spec-experts/2012-December/000159.html

Answer (score 5):

A method reference works just like a lambda, and like a lambda, it doesn't have a "type" on its own. Its type depends on the context where it is used. So your question doesn't really make sense. If you use the method reference in a call to this `MethodRefRunner.execute()` method, then the type of the method reference *will be* an instance of `WHATTYPE` (whatever that is), because that's what the method was declared to accept. If you got it from somewhere else, well, that place will know what type it is.

Comment: his question makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post with an accepted answer, I feel there is more to say. The other answers are of course right, that lambda expressions or method references don't have a well defined type without context. However, when applying them to arguments and maybe assigning the result to a variable, you are providing such a context, so that indeed you can define a static execute() function as you suggested.

When you're not worried about your utility class "MethodRefRunner" getting a bit bigger, you can certainly at least cover the most common cases. The problem is that in principle you need to cover two infinite towers of cases. First are the cases with exactly one return type and an arbitrary number of arguments. Second tower are the cases with again an arbitrary number of arguments but no return type (so "void" which could be seen as special Type "Void", but unfortunately Java refuses to accept lambda-expressions or method-references from one case for the other).
The first tower is covered by `Supplier, Function, BiFunction, ...`
the second tower by `Runnable, Consumer, BiConsumer, ...`
In principle Function alone would be generic enough to cover all of these cases, but only in combination with currying, and there is no built-in currying in Java available. (a curried `BiFunction<X,Y,Z>` is a `Function<X, Function<Y, Z>>`).
So doing without currying, I'd suggest the following:

```
public class MethodRefRunner {
static <X> X execute(Supplier<X> mref) {
    return mref.get();
}
static <X, Y> Y execute(Function<X, Y> mref, X arg) {
    return mref.apply(arg);
}
static <X, Y, Z> Z execute(BiFunction<X, Y, Z> mref, X arg1, Y arg2) {
    return mref.apply(arg1, arg2);
}
// ... (infinitely more needed for each number of arguments)


// same infinite tower again with void return
static void execute(Runnable mref) {
    mref.run();
}

static <X> void execute(Consumer<X> mref, X arg) {
    mref.accept(arg);
}

static <X, Y> void execute(BiConsumer<X, Y> mref, X arg1, Y arg2) {
    mref.accept(arg1, arg2);
}
// ... (infinitely more needed for each number of arguments)


/* so here's the test, the example classes are defined below */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initializing the environment
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    ClassWithMethods object = new ClassWithMethods();


    // applying execute to method references
    execute(object::set, a);
    System.out.println(a == execute(object::get)); // true

    C c = execute(ClassWithMethods::staticMethod, a, b);
    System.out.println(c.equals(execute(object::method, b))); // true
    System.out.println(c.equals(execute(C::new, a, b))); // true

    // A last example with object-method reference for a non-specified object (C::equals instead of c::equals).
    // For some reason my compiler cannot deduce the types itself here, so one has to add a cast
    boolean isEqual = execute((BiFunction<C, C, Boolean>) C::equals, c, execute(C::new, a, b));
    System.out.println(isEqual); // true
}

/* in the following the example-classes used in the test above are defined */
static class A {
}
static class B {
}
static class C {
    A a;
    B b;
    public C(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public boolean equals(C other) {
        return a.equals(other.a) && b.equals(other.b);
    }
}
static class ClassWithMethods {
    A a;

    public A get() {

        return this.a;
    }

    public void set(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public C method(B b) {

        return new C(this.a, b);
    }

    public static C staticMethod(A a, B b) {

        return new C(a, b);
    }
}
}
```