# Partially applied functions with all arguments missing in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

From my understanding, a partially applied function are functions, which we can invoke without 
passing all/some of the required arguments.

```
def add(x:Int, y:Int) = x + y
val paf = add(_ :Int, 3)
val paf1 = add(_ :Int, _ :Int)
```

In the above example, paf1 refers to partially applied function with all the arguments missing and I can invoke is using: `paf1(10,20)` and the original function can be invoked using `add(10,20)`

My question is, what is the extra benefit of creating a partially applied function with all the arguments missing, since the invocation syntax is pretty much the same? Is it just to convert methods into first class functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala's `def` keyword is how you define *methods* and methods are not *functions* (in Scala). So your `add` is not a first-class function entity the way your `paf1` is, even if they're semantically equivalent in what they do with their arguments in producing a result.

Scala will automatically use partial application to turn a method into an equivalent function, which you can see by extending your example a bit:

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
...
val pa2: (Int, Int) => Int = add
pa2: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

This may seem of little benefit in this example, but in many cases there are non-explicit constraints indicating a function is required (or more accurately, constraints specified explicitly elsewhere) that allow you to simply give a (type-compatible) method name in a place where you need a function.

Answer (score 2):

Update: the question was, Why would I ever want an eta-expanded method?  One of the great rhetorical strategies in the Scala bible is that they lead you to an example over many pages.  I employ the Exodus metaphor below because I just saw "The Ten Commandments" with Charlton Heston. I'm not pretending that this answer is more explanatory than Randall's.

You might need someone with lesser rep to note that the big build-up in the bible's book of Exodus is to:

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/first-steps-in-scala.html#step6

`args foreach println`.

The previous step among the "first steps" is, indeed,

`args foreach (arg => println(arg))`

but I'm guessing no one does it that way if the type inference gods are kind.

From the change log in the spec: "a partially unapplied method is now designated m _ instead
of the previous notation &m."  That is, at a certain point, the notion of a "function ptr" became a partial function with no args supplied.  Which is what it is.  Update: "metaphorically."

Comment: Now I know why people are always commenting, "Dude, what's up with the down vote?" which means "not useful." You didn't get one bit of info from this answer? I sure didn't know the syntax used to be an evocative &m. (Until now, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between *Methods* and *functions*.

If you look at the declaration of `List.map` for example, it really expects a function. But the Scala compiler is smart enough to accept both methods and functions.

A quote from [here](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/)

> this trick ... for coercing a method into something where a function is expected, is so easy that even the compiler can detect and do it. In fact, this automatic coercion got an own name – it’s called Eta expansion.

On the other hand, have a look at [Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17143104/2390083); as far as I can tell, it's not that easy there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure others can synthesize a bunch of use-cases for this, but really it's just a consequence of the fact that functions are values.  It would be much weirder if you couldn't pass a function around as a normal value.

Scala's handling of this stuff is a little clunky.  Partial application is usually combined with currying.  I consider it a quirk that you can basically eta-expand any expression using `_`.  What you're effectively doing (modulo Scala's syntactic quirks around currying) by writing `add(_ : Int, _ : Int)` is writing `(x : Int) => (y : Int) => add(x, y)`.  I'm sure you can think of instances where the latter definition might be useful in a program.