# Is it possible to write down a dependent function type in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given

```
trait Foo {
  type Bar
}
```

is there a legal way to write something like `f: (x: Foo) => x.Bar`, so that the return type of the function depends on the argument? An example of use would be

```
def compareOutput(x1: Foo, x2: Foo)(f: (x: Foo) => x.Bar /* illegal */)(comparer: (x1.Bar, x2.Bar) => Boolean) = {
  val y1 = f(x1)
  val y2 = f(x2)
  comparer(y1, y2)
}
```

Comment: See for example [how Miles Sabin uses dependent method types in Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala).

Comment: I don't think that is relevant. He wants to be able to define a function type (as opposed to just defining a method) where the return type depends on the argument value. I belive this is currently impossible. Even you manage to define a type that matches OP's intent, I don't think you would be able to pass a method as the argument `f` because eta-expansion does not support dependent method types. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4751. This would force to define those "dependeant functions" in a rather awkward manner, such as extending a custom trait & implementing its `apply` method

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles: You're right—I may have been reading too quickly. What you describe could be done with Shapeless's polymorphic function values, but not vanilla Scala functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala does not have polymorphic functions as for example Haskell does. A Function type is always concrete.  Only methods can be polymorphic. That does unfortunately mean, that your hypothetical type `(x: Foo) => x.Bar` is not expressible in Scala.

This becomes obvious when converting generic methods to functions: all type information is lost:

```
scala> def foo[Bar](x: Bar): Bar = ???
foo: [Bar](x: Bar)Bar

scala> foo _
res1: Nothing => Nothing = <function1>
```

You might have also noticed that scala does fail to convert methods with dependent types to functions. That is because it is impossible to satisfy your hypothetical type:

```
scala> def foo(x: Foo): x.Bar = ???
foo: (x: Foo)x.Bar

scala> foo _
<console>:10 error: method with dependent type (x: Foo)x.Bar cannot be converted 
                    to function value.
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372916/how-do-i-make-lambda-functions-generic-in-scala/17374315#17374315) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala/2530007#2530007) questions.

---

There are however several solutions to your Problem. One would be to encapsulate your dependently typed method in a helper trait:

```
trait FooFunc {
  def apply(x: Foo): x.Bar
}

def compareOutput(x1: Foo, x2: Foo)(f: FooFunc)(comparer: ...) = {
  val y1 = f(x1)
  val y2 = f(x2)
  comparer(y1,y2)
}
```

You could then create instances of FooFunc which you can pass into your `compareOutput` method.

Answer (score 2):

Scala 3 is expected to be released this year (2020).  It will have (already has, in fact) dependent function types, described here in the "Dotty" documentation:

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/dependent-function-types.html