# Intelligible toString for Lambda Method References

Tags: java, lambda, methodhandle

Is there any way  to get an intelligible `toString` for a lambda generated with a method handle? In pre-Java 8, I have been using the `Function` interface from Guava, and I created a script that generated functions for many of my data classes. I also included a `toString` that clearly identified the class and method that it was for, e.g., `MyItem::getPrice'.

However, with Java 8, although declaring functions have become much easier, I now have no way of identifying what the function is. The most important reason for nice `toString` would be for debugging purposes, but I am sure that there are others as well. It would be nice if this information would be available with reflection, but it is apparently not.

This code snippet

```
Function<String,Integer> func = "ABS"::indexOf;
System.out.println(func);                           
System.out.println(func.getClass());
System.out.println(func.getClass().getSuperclass());
```

produces

```
com.github.jkstrauss.kavve.test.common.TestLambda$$Lambda$1/918221580@5ca881b5
class com.github.jkstrauss.kavve.test.common.TestLambda$$Lambda$1/918221580
class java.lang.Object
```

As you can see there is not even some lambda superclass to work with.

**Clarification**

I am **not** asking how I can define my own `toString`, but how I can determine what class/method this lambda is calling. Defining my own `toString` would defeat the whole purpose of using Java 8 lambdas since I would be required to do a lot more typo-prone work just to get a decent `toString`. I might as well just use my automated script without lambdas.

Comment: Excuse me, but I believe I am asking a different question. That question is asking how to use lambda to define a toString, and I am asking how I can get an automatic, useful description.

Comment: You more or less can't.

Comment: @LouisWasserman What does 'more or less' mean?

Comment: It means I needed a few more letters for StackOverflow to let me write the comment.

Comment: If you want to “determine what class/method this lambda is calling” your question is still a duplicate, in that case of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21860875/2711488). There is no easy solution and the one shown there has its price (don’t use such things for other than debugging). Consider also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26656912/2711488)

Comment: @Holger Guilty as accused. Thank you for the answer anyway. Sometimes these questions are hard to find. I was specifically looking for a solution to use for debugging.

Comment: Since lambda instances are always accessed via one or more `interface`s, you can always create a functional identical [proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.Class:A-java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler-) which wraps the lambda instance and delegates the `interface` method calls to the lambda instance but handles the `toString` method. During debugging you might accept the additional overhead…

Comment: I created a sample implementation of Holger suggestion at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42876841/1325574