# Java 8 find getter name from method reference

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

In some expermients I'd like to write something like this:

```
query(Person.class, eq(Person::lastName, "Hawking"));
```

where `eq` method creates database query part `lastName = 'Hawking'` and `query` as a result return `String` `"SELECT * FROM person WHERE lastName = 'Hawking'"`. This way I'd be able to write type safe queries with short form and without code generation.

Problem is that `eq` as first parameter takes `Supplier<E>`.

**Is it possible to find out via reflection API method name from passed method reference?**

*Even hackish way allowed! :)*

Comment: A method reference is just compile time syntax. At runtime, it's exactly the same as passing a `Supplier` argument.

Comment: If you [call for a hackish way…](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21879031/2711488)   but do me your task sounds like something that could end up in production code some day so I don’t recommend it. And [beware…](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26656912/2711488)

Comment: Ok, the answer is **no**. But in this special case I've figured out how to resolve exact method in **very hackish** way. I invoke passed method reference on mock (Mockito) and intercept invocation. Now I'm able to resolve exact name of passed method. [github.com/tunguski/matsuo-core](https://github.com/tunguski/matsuo-core/blob/73b08bd1b8f2f05fbe52ed4eed199c58b89ca919/matsuo-core/src/main/java/pl/matsuo/core/service/login/LoginService.java#L96).