# Does a method reference in Java 8 have a concrete type and if so, what is it?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, method-reference

This question is pretty closely related to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143104/how-to-indirectly-run-a-method-reference-in-java-8). However, I feel like the accepted answer to that question is not quite as definitive.

So, what **is** the type of a method reference in Java 8? Here's a little demonstration of how a method reference can be "cast" (lifted?) into a `java.util.function.Function`:

```
package java8.lambda;

import java.util.function.Function;

public class Question {
  public static final class Greeter {
    private final String salutation;

    public Greeter(final String salutation) {
      this.salutation = salutation;
    }

    public String makeGreetingFor(final String name) {
      return String.format("%s, %s!", salutation, name);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Greeter helloGreeter = new Greeter("Hello");

    identity(helloGreeter::makeGreetingFor)
      .andThen(g -> "<<<" + g + ">>>")
      .apply("Joe");

    //Compilation error: Object is not a function interface
//    Function
//      .identity()
//      .apply(helloGreeter::makeGreetingFor)
//      .andThen(g -> "<<<" + g + ">>>")
//      .apply("Joe");

    Function
      .<Function<String,String>>identity()
      .apply(helloGreeter::makeGreetingFor)
      .andThen(g -> "<<<" + g + ">>>")
      .apply("Joe");

    //Compilation error: Cannot resolve method 'andThen(<lambda expression>)'
//    (helloGreeter::makeGreetingFor)
//      .andThen(g -> "<<<" + g + ">>>")
//      .apply("Joe");

//    java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory ???
  }

  private static <I,O> Function<I,O> identity(final Function<I,O> fun1) {
    return fun1;
  }
}
```

So, is there a less painful (more straight-forward) way of casting a method reference into a compiled/concrete type which can be passed around?

Comment: `Function<String, String> f = helloGreeter::makeGreetingFor;` ? The type of the method reference is inferred. The same method reference could be used as a Consumer, a Function, or other functional interfaces depending on the context.

Comment: If you feel that a question hasn't been answered well enough, you should offer a bounty on the original question, rather than asking it a second time.  Is there any way in which your question is different from the earlier one, or may I close it as a duplicate?

Comment: i suppose, in essence, they're the same. although the answers here seem to be more specific. i'll close it myself.

Comment: The question belies an incorrect assumption: that all expressions have an intrinsic (bottom-up) type.  Method references and lambdas are examples of _poly expressions_, expressions whose type depends on their context.  The type of a method ref or lambda is simply the type it is being assigned/cast to (provided that type is compatible with the lambda/method ref in question.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz you're making a good point which is quite surprising in the context of a strongly-typed language that Java is supposed to be. Perhaps I'm too used to Scala's approach where  each object and expression has a concrete, compile-time type associated with it.

Comment: @Andrey Your surprise is misplaced; each expression in Java _does_ have a concrete, compile-time type.  What's new here is that, for some expressions, that type may be influenced by (or require type information from) the context in which the expression appears, such as an assignment target type.  Lambdas and method refs have a type, but this is determined not by the expression itself but by extrinsic type information (the assignment or cast target type, of course subject to an applicability check).

Comment: @BrianGoetz my surprise stems from the fact that the left side of an assignment dictates the type of the right side (which seems backwards). in Scala, in the assignment `val fun = helloGreeter.makeGreetingFor _` the right side is of type `Function1[String,String]` and the type of `fun` is inferred to be the same. furthermore, the right side `helloGreeter.makeGreetingFor _`, by itself, is a valid, "compilable" expression because it's just an object of an unambiguous type `Function1[String,String]`...

Comment: I actually think that this question wasn't a duplicate. It focuses on a specific aspect of the other question, but is really different. I have just tried to provide an additional answer to the other question and it wouldn't have fit as an answer to this question here, which for me is a clear sign that it's not a duplicate ; ) . But it seems the issue of this question has been answered here in the answers and comments well enough to not reopen...

Answer (score 6):

Method references are just a syntactic sugar for a function that uses passed parameter as an input argument. So, you can assign them this way:

```
Runnable runnable = System.out::println;
Consumer consumer = System.out::println;
```

types are inferred and depend on a context.

Your case:

```
Function<String, String> foo = helloGreeter::makeGreetingFor;
```

and it is equal to:

```
Function<String, String> foo = s -> helloGreeter.makeGreetingFor(s);
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, method references "are compact, easy-to-read lambda expressions for methods that already have a name" (see [The Java Tutorials - Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)).

So in fact, you are asking for the type of a lambda expression. This is clearly explained in [JLS §15.27.3 (Type of a Lambda Expression)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3).

In short, there are three compatibilities mentioned:

1. Assignment context
2. Invocation context
3. Casting context

The type of a lambda expression or a method reference is inferred by the compiler. As now several contexts can (and must) be taken into account, Java 8 came with big enhancements for type inference.

The only restriction for lambda expressions is that the inferred type must be a [*functional interface*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8). In fact, equal lambda expressions can have different types regarding to their context.

Answer (score 6):

From the [JLS, section 15.13.2, "Type of a Method Reference"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2):

> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context,
>   invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a
>   functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with
>   the function type of the ground target type derived from T.
>
> ...
>
> If a method reference expression is compatible with a target type T,
>   then the type of the expression, U, is the ground target type derived
>   from T.

Basically, the type of the method reference is whatever the context expects it to be. Independent of a context, the method reference doesn't really have a type. There's no way to pass around a "raw" method reference and then turn it into a Function or Consumer or whatever at some later point.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a method reference `helloGreeter::makeGreetingFor`, it has no type.

If you want to give a type to a method reference without assigning it or passing it as an argument (which assigns it to the parameter), you can cast it:

```
String greeting =
    ((Function<String, String>)helloGreeter::makeGreetingFor)
        .apply("Joe");
```