# Java8 Method Reference and generics, type cast needed in some cases

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I am trying to deal with Java8 method references and encountered very strange compile error.

I had a map with object values and I want to provide for user to apply some functions on values.

So I used generic method which takes map key and functional interface as parameter

**And I am wondering why I don't need to cast Method reference to precise real type (in case of trim)**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class ReferenceDiscovering {

    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReferenceDiscovering main = new ReferenceDiscovering();
        main.values.put("key1", " some text with space in start");
        main.values.put("key2", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

        System.out.println(main.values);

        main.applyFunctionByKey("key1", String::trim);
        //        cannot resolve method toLowerCase
        //        COMPILE ERROR HERE. WHY???? WHY NOT FOR trim?
        //        main.applyFunctionByKey("key2", String::toLowerCase);
        main.applyFunctionByKey("key2", (UnaryOperator<String>)String::toLowerCase);


        System.out.println(main.values);
    }

    private <T> void applyFunctionByKey(String key, UnaryOperator<T> binaryOperator) {
        if (values.containsKey(key)) {
            values.put(key, binaryOperator.apply((T)values.get(key)));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> {key1= some text with space in start, key2=AAAAAAAAAAAAAA} {key1=some
>   text with space in start, key2=aaaaaaaaaaaaaa}

Comment: You forgot to mention which compile error you got exactly. It could have to do with the fact that `toLowerCase` has two overloads, but we can't tell without the error. Please [edit] your question and include that.

Comment: Added it into code. Seems to strange for me why it could resolve method after casting if there are 2 of them

Comment: This compilation error makes it sound like @RealSkeptic's theory about overloads is probably correct: https://ideone.com/I1Y7Am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was already given in comments to the question - yes, the problem is that Java cannot decide which method from **String** class should be used (there are two - one with no-arg and second with **Locale**).

This is also related to infering of the method type arguments. In the context of provided code JRE cannot do this.

See also:

- [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)
- [Answer to SO question about method reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29875287/1495324)